# Java-springboot-webflux internal server error in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using spring-boot with web flux and have been trying to hit a basic get on postman which just is supposed to return a string but I'm getting an internal server error. I'm using IntelliJ. Also, no error in the console, and when I try to debug it doesn't get into any class. Below is the code I have:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> printHome() {
        return Mono.just("Welcome to Home");
    }
}

Application.properties: 

server.port=8080

spring.data.mongodb.database=home
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost

spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Comment: What is the Error log in the server? without that no one will be able to help you at all.

Comment: @ThilankaD I'm unable to reproduce the issue because of a lot of changes that I did in my code now but the it looks something like the below but a 500 internal server error

{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-15T19:57:27.205+00:00",
    "path": "/",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "68373fe6-28"
}

Comment: Try to use only `@RestController` on the class and `@GetMapping("/home")` on the method. Then call `localhost:8080/home` on the browser

Comment: Also use `spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE` or complete remove that line from your config

Comment: this question is impossible to answer with the amount of information given. Voted to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### try this-

just **remove this line**

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none  //Delete it
```